# Wildcard search on chinese/japanese characters in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I indexed a text containing chinese words in elastic using default analyzer. My text contains `聲譽` which means **reputation** in chinese.

When I apply a wildcard search using (?) e.g. `聲?` or `?譽` I do not get any results.

However a wildcard search using (*) e.g. `聲*` or `*聲` return results.

Is this how it is supposed to work?

Here's my query:

```
{
    "_source": ["content_id"],
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "txt_1",
            "query": "聲?"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It started working when I used a Chinese analyzer.